# How to allow GPS location on my browser permantly (local web application JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, web, browser, location, local

I get GPS position on my local web application (javascript). It's work but I have an autorization popup each time I start my application. and i don't have the chexbox for "remember my choice".

So, how allow permantly access to the gps on my browser for local application ?

thank you in advance

Comment: _Permanently_? You can't. But, if you want the prompt make sure you are running your file from an HTTP server and not opening it with your file browser.

Comment: Ok thanks ! I expected that, but I thought there would be a trick ... I dont start from an HTTP server. Only local ...

Comment: What platform are you on? MAC/PC/Linux? If Mac or Linux you can start a server from a command prompt. cd to the directly containing the HTML file. Execute `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` (case sensitive). Then point your browser to `http://localhost` and you will see the prompt.

Comment: OK, I will try ! I'm on pc (Windows 10)

Comment: ok thanks ! I started XAMPP and it's work ! I can save my choice for allow the position !! THANKS !

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Randy Casburn !

It's easy ! Just execute a local server (like xampp) and you rimember the choice for the gps location. 
It's impossible whithout http !